# How to specify Specification-Title without creating jar

Tags: java, jai, manifest.mf

When running the test phase my tests fail to the JAI requirement for the code to be run from inside a jar file that contains Specification-Title in the manifest.

Unfortunately mvn test and intellij debug do not build a a jar file (obviously) and so no manifest exists.

Is there an alternative way of setting these values?

Comment: Are you building JAI yourself, from source?

Comment: No it is in a JAR file and referenced in my pom.xml

Comment: If you already have a JAI in a JAR, then what is the problem? I don't think I understand... The Manifest should be in the JAR, with the proper key/values, unless you have a bad JAR. Please add some more detail and relevant stack traces to the question.